# How to read local pdf file and send it as response of expressJS application?

Tags: javascript, express, pdf

This is how I'm generating a pdf file in my expressJS app and send it to the client.
But in some cases I need to read an existing local pdf file and return this as the response.

I don't know how to handle this.

```
import express from 'express'
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/pdf/:id?',
  async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params

    if (id) {
      // how to read local pdf file and output this file?
    } else {
      const doc = new PDFDocument()
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="output.pdf"')
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')

      doc
        .rect(60, 50, 200, 120)
        .fontSize(8)
        .text('some text', 64, 54)
        .stroke()

      doc.pipe(res)
      doc.end()
    }        
  }
)

export default router
```

Comment: Can you get the path of your pdf file by `id`?

Comment: @lx1412 Yes, its always the same directory and the id is the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/pdf/:id?',
  async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params

    if (id) {
      // how to read local pdf file and output this file?
      const filepath = getPathSomehow(id);
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="output.pdf"')
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')

      stream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      const doc = new PDFDocument()
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="output.pdf"')
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')

      doc
        .rect(60, 50, 200, 120)
        .fontSize(8)
        .text('some text', 64, 54)
        .stroke()

      doc.pipe(res)
      doc.end()
    }        
  }
)

export default router
```

You need to implement `getPathSomehow` yourself.

Comment: How do I handle the error if the file is not existing? Do I have to check for existing file first or will `createReadStream` return an error?